# Access Visual FoxPro database from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, dbf, visual-foxpro

I've been trying to access a Visual Fox Pro database from Java for a week now. I'm getting desperate because my project is in a very tied budget and timeframe. (As any other project, I guess, hahaha)

I have a `.dbf`, a `.cdx` and a `.fpt` files. I need to be able to look for a record, extract data, and update data. I don't have a VFP licence.

I hope someone has some pointers or a working example that I can use. If the only way is buying a driver I'll be willing to consider it based on suggestions received.

This is a short description of what I have tried.

I found this [xBaseJ: java objects to read and write to dBase files](http://xbasej.sourceforge.net/). But it doesn't suport CDX index files.

Also found this [Example to access a dbf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079987/2796922). But my tests show this exception: `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC dBase] La tabla externa no tiene el formato esperado.`
I guess a translation to english of this error could be something like: `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] External table is not in the expected format`

Because of that error I think I need a newer driver. In [this microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vfoxpro/bb190232) say they no longer have an ODBC driver, and everybody should use OLE DB Provider. The problem is I haven't found a way to use it from java.

As far as I can tell, [there is no way](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1326929?start=0&tstart=0) to do it directly. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440900/connect-to-oledb-data-source-from-java) someone talking about a JACOB "thingy", and someone comments about the need to create a C++ or C# "something" to be able to do what I need. I think he is talking about [The JACOB Project: A JAva-COM Bridge](http://danadler.com/jacob/). But I also don't know what COM calls would actually have to make.

Haven't been able to find a suitable JDBC driver.

Thank you all.

Ely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the way to do it.

I ended up using JACOB ([from here](http://danadler.com/jacob/) <= upd 2021-10-25: now [here](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project/releases)).

1. Downloaded and installed Visual FoxPro OLE DB driver from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vfoxpro/bb190232 (upd 2021-10-25: links there do not work anymore). the direct link is: [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1A87D8F-2D58-491F-A0FA-95A3289C5FD4&displaylang=en) (upd 2021-10-25: does not work anymore)
2. Downloaded JACOB version 1.17 binary and source code.
3. Added `jacob.jar` as a Java Build Path library
4. Copied `jacob-1.17-x86.dll` to the project directory (same place as eclipse's .project file)
5. Copied `jacob-1.17_src\jacob-1.17\samples\com\jacob\samples\ado` contents to my src directory and:
6. Removed the `ms` directory
7. renamed `test.java` to `Main.java`
8. Changed the connection string to:
   `String connectStr = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\\path\\to\\Data\\;Collating Sequence=general;";`
9. Changed the queryStr to match one of the dbf's name

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Hi, how have o managed to use the provider? I get the message that not suitable driver was found for the provider.

Comment: I just installed the driver as described in step 1. Nothing special.

Comment: Which windows version are you running? I'm running windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I'm using Windows XP in a virtual machin (VMWare)

Comment: I've implemented your solution, and thanks about the idea, it works. But it is not so fast and in my application I have to do frequent queries and the memory grows really fast. I have to restart it every hour.

Comment: if i able to use jacob jar what could be the dirver classname?

Comment: Sorry. Don't know

Answer (score 1):

Since the [jacob approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21945208/1915920) did not work anymore as described and others seemed to work without the OLE DB bridge, I cancelled trying there and successfully did it via [hxtt.com](http://hxtt.com/dbf) drivers:

1. register with some email and the mailed link contains some password to get to the drivers page
2. there one can download the proper driver, e.g. v42 till Java 8 or v43 since Java 9
3. use the following JDBC settings in your env (e.g. Eclipse Database Explorer) to access your DBF files (**e.g.** you have some **`C:\foo\bar.dbf`**):

   - driver jar: e.g. `DBF_JDBC42_tillJava8.jar`
   - driver class: `com.hxtt.sql.dbf.DBFDriver`
   - URL: `jdbc:dbf:/c:/foo/`
   - (if required by your tool with dummy values:)

     - database: `db`
     - user/pass: `usr` / `<empty pass>`

Comment: I can't say if it supports `cdx` and/or `fpt` files

Answer (score 0):

You may find interesting to use a jdbc driver for foxpro files.
I made some quick tests with [this one](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_dbf_jdbc.htm), and it almost looks like you are using a real database in Java.

Regards,

Comment: Great to know. When I have some time to spear, I'll give it a try. I was looking for something like that for days, :)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not suport CDX index files.